# Overflow Error with Macro to come up with all possible combinations of column items

Tags: excel, vba, combinations

So I have this macro that loops through 7 columns and returns 7 other columns that contains every combination of the first 7 columns.

The error I'm having is that I used upper bound to get the number of items in the list. I'm not sure why, but I get an overflow error when I have only 1 item in a column. I figure that VBA isn't the best method to do this, but the rest of our work with the data is done in excel, so it's easier to just keep it close.

It overflows on this line
Set out1 = Range("K2", Range("Q2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7)))

I found a recursive solution to the same combination problem on StackOverflow, but it suffers from the same issue when a column only has 1 item. Should I do an if case? I figure it has to be something with out upperbounds calculated.
Here's the code.

```
Sub Final()


Dim c1() As Variant
Dim c2() As Variant
Dim c3() As Variant
Dim c4() As Variant
Dim c5() As Variant
Dim c6() As Variant
Dim c7() As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim col4 As Range
Dim col5 As Range
Dim col6 As Range
Dim col7 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set col2 = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set col3 = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
Set col4 = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set col5 = Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))
Set col6 = Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
Set col7 = Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown))


c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3
c4 = col4
c5 = col5
c6 = col6
c7 = col7

Set out1 = Range("K2", Range("Q2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7)))
out = out1

j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1
n = 1
o = 1
p = 1
q = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                Do While n <= UBound(c5)
                    Do While o <= UBound(c6)
                        Do While p <= UBound(c7)
                            out(q, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                            out(q, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                            out(q, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                            out(q, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                            out(q, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                            out(q, 6) = c6(o, 1)
                            out(q, 7) = c7(p, 1)
                            q = q + 1
                            p = p + 1
                        Loop
                        p = 1
                        o = o + 1
                    Loop
                    o = 1
                    n = n + 1
                Loop
                n = 1
                m = m + 1
            Loop
            m = 1
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        l = 1
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = 1
    j = j + 1
Loop


out1.Value = out
```

Thanks for any help.
And I know it's not the nicest code, but it works.

**SOLUTION**

```
    Set col1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col2 = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col3 = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col4 = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col5 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col6 = Range(Range("F2"), Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col7 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

If col1.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c1(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c1(1, 1) = col1.Value
Else
    c1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
If col2.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c2(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c2(1, 1) = col1.Value
Else
    c2 = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
    If col3.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c3(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c3(1, 1) = col3.Value
Else
    c3 = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
If col4.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c4(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c4(1, 1) = col4.Value
Else
    c4 = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
    If col5.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c5(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c5(1, 1) = col5.Value
Else
c5 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
If col6.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c6(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c6(1, 1) = col6.Value
Else
    c6 = Range(Range("F2"), Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
If col7.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim c7(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c7(1, 1) = col7.Value
Else
    c7 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End If
```

This ReDims the arrays to be 1 by 1, so they match the range of 1 cell. Works for 1+ items now. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Found the error in this area.
Set col1 = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set col2 = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set col3 = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
Set col4 = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set col5 = Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))
Set col6 = Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
Set col7 = Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown))

Because if you xlDown on 1 item it goes to 10642 or whatever. Now I just need to add a If Else to check to make sure theres items in Row three.

Comment: You can change the syntax from `Set col1 = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))` to this: `Set col1 = Range(Range("A2"),Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` and it will work just as you intend, without having to add an if statement.

Comment: However, apparently variants and ranges aren't compatible? So then I have a type error

But thanks for your help Scott. I think that gets me a little closer to a solution.

Comment: No. They are definitely compatible. There should be something else wrong with your code that is causing it to break.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer, then mark it as such. Will help people in the future.